# Cross-browser CSS for radial gradient and rotate+radius

Tags: css, charts, radial-gradients

Thanks to tools like CSS3 Pie and CSS3Please, I have been able to create cross-browser CSS.

But I am still stuck in two areas (because of Internet Explorer of course):

- radial gradient
- combine rotation and rounded corners

Any pointers to how to address these issues would be appreciated.

My objective is to create a CSS cross-browser pie chart.

Comment: did you look on this example :http://atomicnoggin.ca/blog/2010/02/20/pure-css3-pie-charts/

Comment: Yes, that one too: http://media.smashingmagazine.com/cdn_smash/wp-content/uploads/uploader/images/css3-designs/css3-charts/index.html
My issue is to get this to work in Internet Explorer.

Comment: Use [this](http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/) jQuery plugin for the border-radius and use [this](http://7synth.com/dev/bin/gradient.js) plugin for the gradients in ie.

Answer (score 1):

For IE, you’ll have to use

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient()
```

See the MSDN [documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532997%28VS.85,loband%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

For radial gradient checkout: [Create a radial gradient for Internet Explorer 6/7/8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230250/create-a-radial-gradient-for-internet-explorer-6-7-8)

and for rounded corners simply put these to your css sheet:

```
.someclass {
    /* here you put your PIE.htc file's adress */ 
    behavior:url(/Content/PIE.htc); 
    /* and wish, it behaves like a pie! */
    border-radius:22px 22px 14px 14px;
    /* also you can do smt like */
    /* border-radius:14px 22px 30px 36px; */
    /* or smt more sexy like */ 
    /* border-radius:32px 10px 32px 10px/32px 10px 32px 10px; */
}
```

you can appoint different radius to each corner and it works for all browsers.

and for piechart check this out: http://raphaeljs.com/pie.html