# Create a radial gradient for Internet Explorer 6/7/8

Tags: css

To create a linear gradient in Internet Explorer i used  to adopt this (terrible) code:

`filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#282828', EndColorStr='#185976');`

I wonder wether exists a way to create a radial gradient using filter and DXImageTransoform ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AwuvZ/7/)**

```
#element{
    background: #fff; /* The color you want for the radial gradient */
    width:100px; 
    height:100px;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=100, finishopacity=0, style=2);
}
```

**[Link where I got the info](http://7synth.com/dev/gradients)**

**Radial Gradient**

> For the Radial Gradient we have to create a div-elements. This element
>   is a Overlay for the background. Than we'll use the Alpha-Filter.
>   Alpha will make this element transparent in a special style. style=2
>   is a radial alpha. This means that the center of the element will be
>   full colored (opacity=100) and the opacity will lose to the edges
>   (finishopacity=0)

Comment: brilliant!! it's even work with background-image underneath it! http://jsfiddle.net/edr4M/  i'm not sure about background: transparent; but thats nothing 1px transparent.gif can't fix..!

Comment: I risked my account's security signing onto my SO on an unknown network to offer you an upvote. Thanks (3 year anniversary)

Comment: An old post this be, I know. However, I cannot get jsfiddle to work in ie8!