# CSS radial gradient on ie8 and ie9

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, css

Is there a way to make the following work on ie8 and ie9?

Thanks

```
background: -moz-moz-radial-gradient(center top, farthest-side, rgba(175,175,175,0.3) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center top, farthest-side, 0px, center top, farthest-side, 100%, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center top, farthest-side, rgba(175,175,175,0.3) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-radial-gradient(center top, farthest-side, rgba(175,175,175,0.3) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Opera 12+ */
background: -ms-ms-radial-gradient(center top, farthest-side, rgba(175,175,175,0.3) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: radial-gradient(farthest-side at center top, rgba(175,175,175,0.3) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* W3C */
```

Comment: You've doubled up the `-moz-` and `-ms-` prefixes. Those definitely won't work.

Answer (score 2):

I note that you've got a problem in the CSS in the question where you've doubled up the `-moz-` and `-ms-` prefixes. Those definitely won't work like that.

Ignoring that, you're right that radial gradients are a problem in old IE. In fact, CSS gradients in general are problematic in old IE versions because CSS gradients are not supported in IE 9 or earlier.

My normal solution to CSS gradients in IE 6-9 is [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/).

However for radial gradients this isn't sufficient, because CSS3Pie doesn't currently support radial gradients. See the [css3pie documentation for more info on this](http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/). To quote:

> Radial gradients are not supported at this time; this feature is planned for a future release (see issue #2) but it may turn out to be impossible to implement in IE 6-8 due to VML's strange radial gradient behavior.

The other option you have is to use IE's `filter` style, (and accept all the weird issues and quirks that come with it). Even here, radial gradients are difficult, but there is a solution here that might help: [Create a radial gradient for Internet Explorer 6/7/8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230250/create-a-radial-gradient-for-internet-explorer-6-7-8)

Comment: Thanks for the info Spudley, just a thought would it not be easier to have some kind of media query detect the users browser and place in a png if their using ie?

Comment: @a_knife_a_fork - yep, an old-school png would probably do the trick (you could even consider using a base64 encoded image embedded in the CSS if wanted to keep it as a CSS solution). The downside to that of course is that it's not scalable, and particularly for a radial gradient it would be a relatively big extra file to download (linear gradients done that way can be a single pixel high, which is smaller and partially scalable, but for a radial gradient you'd need to have the png as the whole image)