# solution for ugly font in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, radial-gradients

I'm using

```
 background-image: -ms-radial-gradient(left top, circle cover, #dbd7fa 0%, #f7f6fe 56.12%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorstr='#dbd7fa', endColorstr='#f7f6fe',GradientType=0);
```

to make a radial background in a div, but the font rendering of IE is ugly, like in some jquery effects (fadeIn, fadeOut, ecc.).
The font used is Arial.

Does anybody know a hack to get the font normal?

Thanks in advance for helping

Comment: If i'm removing the filter, there's no radial gradient anymore in IE8

Comment: Is it the end of the world? Why not just use a traditional background image? You know, the way we made gradients in Firefox and Chrome before CSS gradients?

Comment: It's not the end of the world (i hope so) :-)), but i'm asking if there is any solution.

Comment: @Kolink: Background images have all sorts of problems, for example they cannot adapt to different sizes of an element. Especially in IE. Anyway, my favorite way to handle this would be to display a hint for IE users and leave out the gradient for them (or leave it in and live with the ugly font).

Answer (score 0):

Have you search carefully in stackoverflow before asking ?

I found these articles: [Create a radial gradient for Internet Explorer 6/7/8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230250/create-a-radial-gradient-for-internet-explorer-6-7-8), [CSS radial gradient on ie8 and ie9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102420/css-radial-gradient-on-ie8-and-ie9)

Also consider reading this page: http://7synth.com/dev/gradients which contains javascript file

> A website, beautiful and fast loading is always a contrast. Smooth
>   colored gradients with CSS can help, but not all Browser and not one
>   library support this. With the "gradient.js" from 7synth you can have
>   full and easy support for radial and linear gradients in
>   InternetExplorer (IE), Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera and more... .