# Linear Gradient in IE8 no-repeat fixed center

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, linear-gradients

I am trying to create a linear gradient background for my website that is compatible with IE8.

I want the IE8 equivalent of:

```
background: radial-gradient(#198548,#FFFFFF) no-repeat fixed center;
```

I managed to create a linear gradient with:

filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#198548', EndColorStr='#FFFFFF');

However, I need it to be no-repeat fixed center since my page extends as I scroll the page (paging). Whenever this happens, the background eventually turns completely white.

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a radial gradient for Internet Explorer 6/7/8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230250/create-a-radial-gradient-for-internet-explorer-6-7-8)

Comment: @Lowkase jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/urzur/FECv7/ . It is important that you run this fiddle on your regular browser and then see it using jsfiddle draft in IE8 (http://jsfiddle.net/draft/). More information about jsfiddle drag can be found: http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html

Comment: @Paulie_D this is not a duplicate, the problem here is not generating the gradient but rather making  no-repeat fixed center so when you scroll down the page it does not eventually turn into a white background.